# Visual Studio 2010 target framework 2.0 vs working on Visual Studio 2005 pros and cons

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2005

I'm new to Visual Studio 2010 and have both Visual Studio 2005 and 2010 installed on my PC.

I need to work on a windows application that needs to run under the 2.0 .net framework, but I'm not sure which version of Visual Studio would be more suitable for developing this application. Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd go with 2010 - just due to the new refactoring support. And performance-wise my findings suggest that 2010 is somewhat better (especially if you have a decent workstation - especially graphics adapter).

Answer (score 1):

**Advantages**

- We can start taking advantage of the new `tooling features`, without having to immediately upgrade the clients and servers running our application’s to .NET 4.0.The improved multi-targeting support will ensure that this experience is even better and more accurate than before.

**Disadvantages**

- If some of our team members still using visual studio 2005, there will be a problem when checking in project files.